# Fill UV squares completely in all margin

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I try to UV in a cubic model using Blender (v2.79).

I don't know how to do the same as this and **must be like this**:

[image]

The cubic model that I'm trying to UV like the previous even using Method: Angle-Based(**These aren't the UV that I want**):

[image]

What it should do?

Comment: Are you trying to unwrap all your model's polygons onto the same square of the UV-space? If so, you can just do ANY unwrap you like and then call the Unwrap Menu again and hit "Reset".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unwrap the UV, so that every Quad fills the UV space from (0, 0) to (1, 1), select the faces in the 3D View, press <kbd>U</kbd> and choose *Reset* from the unwrap dialog. (The bottom most option.)